# Retrieve list items with date query using client object model

Tags: client-object-model, custom-list, csom, caml-query

I wrote this caml query to get the data. the query i wrote-

```
<View>
<Query>
    <Where>
    <And>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='AccNo' />
        <Value Type='Text'>0258</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='EmpInTime' />
        <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='FALSE'>2017-02-23 00:00:00</Value>
    </Eq>
    </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

this should return only one row. but it returns more. what is the problem with this query?

**Update:** Tried "2017-02-23 T00:00:00Z" too as the DateTime value.

Comment: can you try using it as `2017-02-23 T00:00:00Z` ?

Comment: try this but doesnot work

Comment: Please try to pass ISO8601DateTime in CAML query like `SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now);`.

Comment: still doesnot work

Comment: `2017-02-23T12:00:00Z` should work fine. Make sure there are no spaces and if the column doesn't include time value, it is `12:00:00` by default, not `00:00:00` :)

Comment: Also, using `<eq>` with DateTime values is not recommended, better use other comparissons like `<leq>`,`<geq>`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works

the query is:

```
<View>
 <Query>
  <Where>
   <And>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='AccNo' />
     <Value Type='Text'>0258</Value>
   </Eq>
    <Geq>
     <FieldRef Name='EmpInTime' />
     <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>2017-02-23T12:00:00Z</Value>
    </Geq>
    <Leq>
     <FieldRef Name='EmpInTime' />
     <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>2017-02-24T12:00:00Z</Value>
    </Leq>
  </And>
 </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

Change the time with `2017-02-23T12:00:00Z` and use `Geq` and `Leq` in stead of `Eq`.

Answer (score -1):

try below just updated

```
<View>
 <Query>
  <Where>
   <And>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='AccNo' />
     <Value Type='Text'>0258</Value>
   </Eq>
    <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='EmpInTime' />
     <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'>2017-02-23T00:00:00Z</Value>
    </Eq>
  </And>
 </Where>
</Query>
</View>
```